# How many missions do I need to complete to upgrade my Operation Breakout badge?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So the new badge is weird in that it doesn't rank up based on comp wins, but based on operation missions completed on official matchmaking servers.

How many missions would I have to complete to get to Silver, and even to Gold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete 5 missions to get a Silver Breakout badge.
Complete 15 missions to get a Gold Breakout Badge.